# Replacing ampersand

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have to replace `&` with '`and`' in a table,
why is this statement not working?

```
UPDATE pt_hotels set clean_hotel_title = REPLACE(clean_hotel_title, '%&%','and');
```

while this is selecting the names I wish to change?

```
SELECT clean_hotel_title from pt_hotels
WHERE clean_hotel_title like '%&%';
```

I am using mysql 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `%` from `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE pt_hotels set clean_hotel_title = REPLACE(clean_hotel_title, '&','and');
```

Also you can add `WHERE clean_hotel_title like '%&%'` to your `UPDATE`, to keep transaction size down:

```
UPDATE pt_hotels set clean_hotel_title = REPLACE(clean_hotel_title, '&','and')
WHERE clean_hotel_title like '%&%'
```

Comment: its done, i have tryed everything but that cause i thouht that '&' would search only to & and not to bad&breafast thank you